# What's "time" in getAdaptedTraveltime()?

Tags: python, sumo

I'm working with TraCI and now I'm using custom weights on the edges. To do so, I used `traci.vehicle.setAdaptedTraveltime(vehID, edgeID, time=<Custom_time>, begTime=None, endTime=None)`. Now I want to double check and see if I change it correctly with my `<Custom_time>` and I want to use `traci.vehicle.getAdaptedTraveltime(vehID, time, edgeID)`.

Why do I have to declare the attribute `time`, if it is the value I want to retrieve? Am I missing something?

[Sumo,TraCI documentation](https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._vehicle.html#VehicleDomain-getAdaptedTraveltime)

[GitHub, TraCI documentation](https://github.com/DLR-TS/sumo/blob/40b80d93bdd2c097ff41a56d7c5b21c59b9d7d0d/tools/traci/_vehicle.py#L30)

Comment: I guess the `time` you provide is a time-of-day, or a date (i.e. *when* you travel), and what it returns is a duration (i.e. *how long* you travel).

Comment: @mkrieger1 "time" is supposed to be the time in seconds needed to travel a defined edge of the network, usually SUMO sets the travel time of each edge based on parameters like: length of the edge, max speed allowed, ecc.